# Empty data on form that uploads a file on codeigniter controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to upload files with this form

```
<form action="/ajax/images/store_image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Selecciona una imagen</label>
           <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
           <input type="hidden" name="{{ csrf_name }}" value="{{ csrf_hash }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

And this is the codeigniter controller that  listen the request

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/Common/Backend_Controller.php';

/**
 * This class provides all the methods & functionallity of public "Batch operations" page.
 */
class Images extends Backend_Controller {

    public function storeImage(){
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```

It only show `$_POST` content ..and its always empty

Comment: what you get when you dump `$_FILES`?

Comment: You set the name attribute to input and then get the file using 
$_FILES['attribute_name']['name']

Comment: Your file input field is missing the name attribute. Form fields without a name do not become part of the form submission data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not dump the multipart form data using `$_POST`. You have to use `$_FILES`.

```
NOTE: name attribute is missing from the file input. The name attribute is mandatory for submitting the form data.
```